# Android studio is not properly installed

Tags: android

extra android m2 repository,extra google m2 repository and 2 more sdk components were not installed.
This message was displaying after the installation of Android studio.
Some components as Android sdk manager and AVD are not working properly.
Please guide me how to fix the problem.

Comment: please elaborate your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Android SDK Manager and Select `Android SDK Tools` and `Android SDK Platform-tools` and update and then restart Android SDK Manager you will find Extras now install `Android Support Repository` inside Extras.If this doesn't help i guess you have to Re-install the software while reinstalling keep your internet connection on it may download packages and files form internet.
See to it that you have downloaded Android SDK properly without any issue.
I hope this answer helps..